# Apache not making core dump even though kill -11 makes one

Tags: apache, coredump

Hope this is something simple, but maybe not.

I have 4 **RHEL5** web boxes that are setup behind a load balancer. All serve the majority of their content off of an `NFS` share.

Occasionally (twice a day or less) I'll see a note in the syslog from the kernel about a segfault from apache:

```
/var/log/messages.2:Sep 13 14:09:14 20050lpweb01 kernel: httpd[10006]: segfault at 00007fffae2eede8 rip 00002ab21a4045d4 rsp 00007fffae2eedd0 error 6
```

Sometimes, this is accompanied by a message to the apache error log about it as well, but not always:

```
# grep -ic seg /var/log/messages* |egrep -v '0$'
/var/log/messages.2:1
/var/log/messages.3:2
/var/log/messages.4:4
# zgrep -ic seg /var/log/httpd/error_log* |egrep -v '0$'
/var/log/httpd/error_log:1
/var/log/httpd/error_log.10.gz:1
/var/log/httpd/error_log.17.gz:1
/var/log/httpd/error_log.19.gz:1
/var/log/httpd/error_log.23.gz:1
/var/log/httpd/error_log.24.gz:2
/var/log/httpd/error_log.25.gz:1
/var/log/httpd/error_log.28.gz:2
/var/log/httpd/error_log.30.gz:1
/var/log/httpd/error_log.31.gz:1
/var/log/httpd/error_log.35.gz:1
/var/log/httpd/error_log.39.gz:4
/var/log/httpd/error_log.42.gz:1
/var/log/httpd/error_log.44.gz:3
/var/log/httpd/error_log.46.gz:1
```

I've setup core dumping per instructions all over the web:

```
echo "ulimit -c unlimited >/dev/null 2>&1" >> /etc/profile
echo "DAEMON_COREFILE_LIMIT='unlimited'" >> /etc/sysconfig/init
echo 1 > /proc/sys/fs/suid_dumpable
echo "core.%p" > /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern
echo "CoreDumpDirectory /home/coredump" > /etc/httpd/conf.d/core_dumps.conf
mkdir /home/coredump
chown apache: /home/coredump
source /etc/profile
service httpd stop
service httpd start
```

When I "induce" a segfault (kill -11 ), the coredump is generated:

```
/var/log/httpd/error_log:[Sat Sep 15 20:43:32 2012] [notice] child pid 20746 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /home/coredumps
```

But when the segfault occurs on its own, no coredump is made:

```
/var/log/httpd/error_log:[Sat Sep 15 12:03:44 2012] [notice] child pid 10652 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
```

Why is this happening and how can I make sure the core dump happens every time?

We are running **PHP 5.2** but other than that, everything is installed from standard **RHEL** or **EPEL** repos.

Comment: May be the core dump was generated into different folder than `/home/coredump`. I would suggest you do a quick search: `find / -name 'core.[0-9]*'` to see if you find anything.

Comment: I did that back at the time that I was troubleshooting this but none were found.

The best answer I could come up with was that either a) the kernel won't allow core dumps to be sent to a mounted NFS share, or b) Apache won't do the same.